# The explicit solution of the recurrence $f(2n) = f(2n + 1) = 2f(n)$ with $f(1) = 1$

Tags: recurrence-relations

> Given that $f(1) = 1$ and for $n\geq1$, $$f(2n) = f(2n + 1) = 2f(n)$$
>   show that for every natural number $n$, $f(n)$ is the largest power of $2$ less than or equal to $n$.

I don't understand what is going on. Am I asked to prove that $f(n) = 2^{k}$ and $k\leq n$?

Comment: Not exactly. You are asked to show that for all $n$, we have $f(n)=2^k$ for some $k$, and that (1) We have $f(n)\le n$ for all $n$ but (2) We also have $n<2f(n)$ for all $n$. A natural approach to a problem like this is to use (strong) induction, considering cases according to whether $n$ is even or odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a few values to see if you can see a pattern:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
k&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16\\
\hline
f(k)&1&2&2&4&4&4&4&8&8&8&8&8&8&8&8&16
\end{array}\tag{1}
$$
The pattern seems to be
$$
f(k)=2^{\lfloor\log_2(k)\rfloor}\tag{2}
$$
Looking at $(1)$, we have that $(2)$ holds for $k=1$.

For $n>1$, assume that $(2)$ holds for all $k\lt n$ and see if we can show that it holds for $k=n$.

If $n$ is even, since $n/2<n$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
f(n)
&=2f(n/2)\\
&=2\cdot2^{\lfloor\log_2(n/2)\rfloor}\\
&=2\cdot2^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor-1}\\
&=2^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
and therefore, $(2)$ holds.

If $n$ is odd, since $(n-1)/2<n$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
f(n)
&=2f((n-1)/2)\\
&=2\cdot2^{\lfloor\log_2((n-1)/2)\rfloor}\\
&=2\cdot2^{\lfloor\log_2(n-1)\rfloor-1}\\
&=2^{\lfloor\log_2(n-1)\rfloor}\\
&=2^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
and therefore, $(2)$ holds.